# Confused about accessing values in an array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm trying to pull out the values from an array with embedded objects and I can't figure out how to reference the items I need. I call a function (working in WordPress with LearnDash plugins) which returns an array. The call I use and the echo to see the structure is:

```
$my_lessons = learndash_get_course_lessons_list( $course_id, $user_id,  $query_args );
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($my_lessons);
    echo "</pre>";
```

It returns:

```
array(10) {
  [1]=>
  array(9) {
    ["sno"]=>
    int(1)
    ["id"]=>
    int(38155)
    ["post"]=>
    object(WP_Post)#9918 (24) {
      ["ID"]=>
      int(38155)
      ["post_author"]=>
      string(1) "9"
      ["post_date"]=>
      string(19) "2023-10-07 15:01:55"
      ["post_date_gmt"]=>
      string(19) "2023-10-07 15:01:55"
      ["post_content"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_title"]=>
      string(45) "Lesson 1: Happy Family, Healthy Brain (adult)"
      ["post_excerpt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_status"]=>
      string(7) "publish"
      ["comment_status"]=>
      string(6) "closed"
      ["ping_status"]=>
      string(6) "closed"
      ["post_password"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_name"]=>
      string(41) "lesson-1-happy-family-healthy-brain-adult"
      ["to_ping"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["pinged"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_modified"]=>
      string(19) "2023-10-07 15:01:57"
      ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
      string(19) "2023-10-07 15:01:57"
      ["post_content_filtered"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_parent"]=>
      int(0)
      ["guid"]=>
      string(68) "https://xxx.xxx.com/?post_type=sfwd-lessons&p=38155"
      ["menu_order"]=>
      int(1)
      ["post_type"]=>
      string(12) "sfwd-lessons"
      ["post_mime_type"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["comment_count"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["filter"]=>
      string(3) "raw"
    }
    ["permalink"]=>
    string(121) "https://xxx.xxx.com/courses/sfp-finding-home-adult-english/lessons/lesson-1-happy-family-healthy-brain-adult/"
    ["class"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["status"]=>
    string(9) "completed"
    ["sample"]=>
    string(13) "is_not_sample"
    ["sub_title"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["lesson_access_from"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
```

and so on for each lesson.

I want to be able to pull out the id (which is 38155) and the post_title from the object (Lesson 1: Happy Family, Healthy Brain (adult)) but I am confused on how to proceed. Any suggestions?

I tried looping though the array using

```
foreach ($my_lessons as $k => $v) {
    $my_return .= "<br>".$k."<br>"; 
    $my_return .= "<br>lesson: ".$v["id"]."<br>"; 
    }
```

This gets me the ids, but then I am not sure how to get the post_title.

Comment: `$v['post']->post_title`

Comment: It's `$v['post']->ID` if you're trying to get the ID of `38155`

Comment: Why have two users commented resolving advice, but have not voted to close?  Comments are not the place on the page to deliver resolving advice.  In rare cases, it can be appropriate to give some guidance if you are also voting to close.  Please help to maintain Stack Overflow's content.

Comment: @Dottie It is also possible to "destructure" the rows and only pick out the parts you need access to.  `foreach ($my_lessons as $k => ['post' => $obj]) { /* access $k, $obj->ID, and $obj->post_title */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array returned by learndash_get_course_lessons_list() includes an object, namely an instance of the Wordpress WP_Post object. You therefore have to use a combination of array and object syntax to access the variable you want.

The WP_Post object is in the ['post'] field of each row in your array. In this case `$my_lessons[0]['post']->ID` and `$my_lessons[0]['post']->post_title` are the full names of variables you need (without using a foreach loop).

You could output the ID and name something like this:

```
$my_return = '';
foreach ($my_lessons as $k => $v) {
    $my_return .= "<br>Lesson name: " . $v["post"]->post_title . "<br>"; 
    $my_return .= "<br>Lesson id: " . $v["post"]->ID. "<br>"; 
}
echo $my_return;
```

Comment: Please vote to close duplicate questions instead of answering so that the Roomba can do its job.  When you answer a duplicate question, the Roomba cannot purge the unneeded page.